# Doze mode and App Standby

Tags: android, android-6.0-marshmallow

How can I know in my app if the phone is in Doze mode or if my app is in Standby mode?

Can I also know it by using some subscribing approach?

Comment: I found the answer in the Android M Preview documentation. PowerManager isDeviceIdleMode() and also through a broadcast ACTION_DEVICE_IDLE_MODE_CHANGED

Comment: This is for idle mode. How will i identify standby mode for app?

Comment: I did not test it, but in theory both Doze and App Standby modes will result in an 'idle' state. Need to check this with the current Android M Preview 3 though... The docs could be clearer on this.

Answer (score 4):

> There's a difference between **App Standby** (where your app goes to
>   sleep because it's lonely) and **Doze** (where the system went to
>   sleep because users have lives).
>
> **Doze** only works when your device remains stationary. If you pick it up or wake the screen, Doze mode is deactivated and the timer
>   resets. It won’t ever turn on when the phone is sitting in your pocket
>   unless you’re sitting remarkably still. Doze simply keeps your phone
>   from burning through the battery while it’s asleep on a desk or table
>   or something.
>
> An app that goes into **Standby** loses all network access and all its
>   background sync jobs are suspended. These restrictions are temporarily
>   lifted when your phone is plugged in and for a few minutes every day
>   or two. This gives suspended apps a chance to run any pending sync
>   jobs, but they won’t be allowed to continue running. A high-priority
>   push notification will also be able to wake an app from Standby for a
>   short time.

**Note:** Google has also noted that it isn’t acceptable for apps to
 fire off notifications simply to remain exempt from App Standby. This
 sort of behavior can get an app banned from the Play Store.

For more details with testing **Doze and App Standby**, Please visit this link: https://developer.android.com/training/monitoring-device-state/doze-standby.html

Thanks!

Comment: Can you give me the source of this statement -> Google has also noted that it isn’t acceptable for apps to fire off notifications simply to remain exempt from App Standby. This sort of behavior can get an app banned from the Play Store.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to do anything to manage Standby mode. You just need to manage you lifecycle as usual. There will be a time in the day when you app is gonna be resumed (so you can sync data and resume delayed jobs), but notifications and alarms will always bring your app out of standby.

Check this out: https://plus.google.com/+AndroidDevelopers/posts/76eh5MaJaXj?linkId=18331776

Comment: if you make your app device admin then it will not stnadby